Problems deserializing XML files with nested namespaces
I have the following XML file (excerpt):
<AutoindexBundle xmlns:i="...www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="...dev.mysite.com/settings/settingsExchange">
    <Autoindex xmlns:d2p1="...dev.mysite.com/settings/workflows/autoindex">
        <Header xmlns="...//dev.mysite.com/settings/bpsprocesses/common">
            <Guid xmlns="...//dev.mysite.com/settings/interop">0a3b7b31-907a-40bf-b55f-747046dc7ea2</Guid>
            <ID xmlns="...//dev.mysite.com/settings/interop">413</ID>
            <Name xmlns="...//dev.mysite.com/settings/interop">SD_CLEAR_STATUS</Name>
            <Description>Löscht die Einträge im Statusfeld</Description>
        </Header>
        <d2p1:AIMatchOptionSettings>
            <d2p1:MatchCodes>
...

I would like to deserialize this file in order to obtain the information under "Header.Name", for example. I've already looked at many examples on the Internet but somehow they don't all match my source file.
I first created a class in VB.NET using the "Insert special" function and saved it in a module called "AutoindesBundle". Here is an excerpt:
Public Class AutoindexBundle
    ' HINWEIS: Für den generierten Code ist möglicherweise mindestens .NET Framework 4.5 oder .NET Core/Standard 2.0 erforderlich.
    '''<remarks/>
    <System.SerializableAttribute(),
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True, [Namespace]:="...//dev.mysite.com/settings/settingsExchange"),
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute([Namespace]:="...//dev.mysite.com/settings/settingsExchange", IsNullable:=False)>
    Partial Public Class AutoindexBundle
        Private autoindexField As AutoindexBundleAutoindex
        Private guidField As String
        Private ruleField As Object
        Private scheduleSettingsField As AutoindexBundleScheduleSettings
        '''<remarks/>
        Public Property Autoindex() As AutoindexBundleAutoindex
            Get
                Return Me.autoindexField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.autoindexField = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        '''<remarks/>
        Public Property Guid() As String
            Get
                Return Me.guidField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.guidField = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        '''<remarks/>
        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable:=True)>
        Public Property Rule() As Object
            Get
                Return Me.ruleField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.ruleField = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        '''<remarks/>
        Public Property ScheduleSettings() As AutoindexBundleScheduleSettings
            Get
                Return Me.scheduleSettingsField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.scheduleSettingsField = Value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
    '''<remarks/>
    <System.SerializableAttribute(),
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True, [Namespace]:="...dev.mysite.com/settings/settingsExchange")>
    Partial Public Class AutoindexBundleAutoindex
        Private headerField As Header
        Private aIMatchOptionSettingsField As AIMatchOptionSettings
        Private extDBActionsField As ExtDBActions
        Private extDBSourceField As ExtDBSource
        Private externalDataSourceTypeField As String
        Private fCActionsField As FCActions
        Private fCSourceField As FCSource
        Private iteratedRecordsAreInField As String
        Private ruleGuidField As String
        Private versionField As String
        '''<remarks/>
        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute([Namespace]:="...dev.mysite.com/settings/bpsprocesses/common")>
        Public Property Header() As Header
            Get
                Return Me.headerField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.headerField = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        '''<remarks/>
        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute([Namespace]:="...dev.mysite.com/settings/workflows/autoindex")>
        Public Property AIMatchOptionSettings() As AIMatchOptionSettings
            Get
                Return Me.aIMatchOptionSettingsField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.aIMatchOptionSettingsField = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        '''<remarks/>
        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute([Namespace]:="...dev.mysite.com/settings/workflows/autoindex")>
        Public Property ExtDBActions() As ExtDBActions
            Get
                Return Me.extDBActionsField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.extDBActionsField = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        '''<remarks/>
        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute([Namespace]:="...//dev.mysite.com/settings/workflows/autoindex")>
        Public Property ExtDBSource() As ExtDBSource
            Get
                Return Me.extDBSourceField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.extDBSourceField = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        '''<remarks/>
        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute([Namespace]:="...//dev.mysite.com/settings/workflows/autoindex")>
        Public Property ExternalDataSourceType() As String
            Get
                Return Me.externalDataSourceTypeField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.externalDataSourceTypeField = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        '''<remarks/>
        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute([Namespace]:="...//dev.mysite.com/settings/workflows/autoindex")>
        Public Property FCActions() As FCActions
            Get
                Return Me.fCActionsField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.fCActionsField = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        '''<remarks/>
        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute([Namespace]:="...//dev.mysite.com/settings/workflows/autoindex")>
        Public Property FCSource() As FCSource
            Get
                Return Me.fCSourceField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.fCSourceField = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        '''<remarks/>
        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute([Namespace]:="...//dev.mysite.com/settings/workflows/autoindex")>
        Public Property IteratedRecordsAreIn() As String
            Get
                Return Me.iteratedRecordsAreInField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.iteratedRecordsAreInField = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        '''<remarks/>
        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute([Namespace]:="...//dev.mysite.com/settings/workflows/autoindex")>
        Public Property RuleGuid() As String
            Get
                Return Me.ruleGuidField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.ruleGuidField = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        '''<remarks/>
        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute([Namespace]:="...dev.mysite.com/settings/workflows/autoindex")>
        Public Property Version() As String
            Get
                Return Me.versionField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.versionField = Value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
    '''<remarks/>
    <System.SerializableAttribute(),
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True, [Namespace]:="http://dev.mysite.com/settings/bpsprocesses/common"),
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute([Namespace]:="...//dev.mysite.com/settings/bpsprocesses/common", IsNullable:=False)>
    Partial Public Class Header
        Private guidField As String
        Private idField As UShort
        Private nameField As String
        Private descriptionField As String
        '''<remarks/>
        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute([Namespace]:="...dev.mysite.com/settings/interop")>
        Public Property Guid() As String
            Get
                Return Me.guidField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.guidField = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        '''<remarks/>
        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute([Namespace]:="...//dev.mysite.com/settings/interop")>
        Public Property ID() As UShort
            Get
                Return Me.idField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.idField = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        '''<remarks/>
        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute([Namespace]:="...//dev.mysite.com/settings/interop")>
        Public Property Name() As String
            Get
                Return Me.nameField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.nameField = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        '''<remarks/>
        Public Property Description() As String
            Get
                Return Me.descriptionField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.descriptionField = Value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
    '''<remarks/>
.
.
.

I then tried to read the information from the Header element:
Private Sub DeserializeObject(ByVal filename As String)
        Console.WriteLine("Reading with XmlReader")
        Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(AutoindexBundle.Header))
        Dim fs As New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open)
        Dim reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(fs)
        Dim test As AutoindexBundle.Header
        test = CType(serializer.Deserialize(reader), AutoindexBundle.Header)
        fs.Close()
        Console.Write(test.Guid & ControlChars.Tab &
                      test.ID & ControlChars.Tab &
                      test.Name & ControlChars.Tab &
                      test.Description & ControlChars.Tab)
    End Sub

But unfortunately I get the following error messages in the line test = CType(....:
System.InvalidOperationException: "There is an error in XML document (1, 40)."
Innere Ausnahme 1:
InvalidOperationException:  was not expected.
What am I doing wrong here or what do I have to change to make this work?

If you serialize your classes using some test data, then you'll see what the issue is. You'll only be able to deserialize data that exactly matches how it's serialized. If you'd like assistance here, you'll need to provide complete, valid, XML. This doesn't necessarily mean that you need to post your entire XML file, but rather create a minimal reproducible example that's representative of your XML - it should be valid XML.

Here is a shortened and neutralized version of an original file:
<AutoindexBundle xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://dev.mysite.com/settings/settingsExchange">
    <Autoindex xmlns:d2p1="http://dev.mysite.com/settings/workflows/autoindex">
        <Header xmlns="http://dev.mysite.com/settings/bpsprocesses/common">
            <Guid xmlns="http://dev.mysite.com/settings/interop">978094cb-6cb5-4782-afdd-bf4cd11cf4ba</Guid>
            <ID xmlns="http://dev.mysite.com/settings/interop">469</ID>
            <Name xmlns="http://dev.mysite.com/settings/interop">X_SD_CLEAR_DEL</Name>
            <Description>Löscht die Einträge im Statusfeld</Description>
        </Header>
        <d2p1:AIMatchOptionSettings>
            <d2p1:MatchCodes/>
            <d2p1:MultiMatchMode>NoMatch</d2p1:MultiMatchMode>
        </d2p1:AIMatchOptionSettings>
        <d2p1:ExtDBActions>
            <d2p1:MatchActions>
                <d2p1:DeleteRow>false</d2p1:DeleteRow>
                <d2p1:Fields/>
            </d2p1:MatchActions>
            <d2p1:NoMatchActions>
                <d2p1:Fields/>
                <d2p1:InsertRow>false</d2p1:InsertRow>
            </d2p1:NoMatchActions>
        </d2p1:ExtDBActions>
        <d2p1:ExtDBSource>
            <d2p1:AIDataSource i:type="d2p1:FixedEntriesDataSource">
                <d2p1:DSGuid>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</d2p1:DSGuid>
                <d2p1:SourceName i:nil="true"/>
            </d2p1:AIDataSource>
            <d2p1:DSFields/>
            <d2p1:FilterOption>AllDocuments</d2p1:FilterOption>
            <d2p1:UsedFilter xmlns:d4p1="http://dev.mysite.com/settings/filter">
                <d4p1:Condition i:nil="true"/>
                <d4p1:Logic>And</d4p1:Logic>
            </d2p1:UsedFilter>
        </d2p1:ExtDBSource>
        <d2p1:ExternalDataSourceType>FixedEntries</d2p1:ExternalDataSourceType>
        <d2p1:FCActions>
            <d2p1:MatchActions>
                <d2p1:DeleteRow>false</d2p1:DeleteRow>
                <d2p1:Fields>
                    <d2p1:IndexField i:type="d2p1:IndexDeletion">
                        <d2p1:Field>DEL</d2p1:Field>
                        <d2p1:Value i:nil="true"/>
                    </d2p1:IndexField>
                </d2p1:Fields>
            </d2p1:MatchActions>
            <d2p1:NoMatchActions>
                <d2p1:Fields/>
                <d2p1:InsertRow>false</d2p1:InsertRow>
            </d2p1:NoMatchActions>
        </d2p1:FCActions>
        <d2p1:FCSource>
            <d2p1:AIDataSource i:type="d2p1:FileCabinetDataSource">
                <d2p1:DSGuid>0c3b26ac-305e-48c5-952b-6aee1518cd50</d2p1:DSGuid>
                <d2p1:SourceName>Stammdaten</d2p1:SourceName>
                <d2p1:UserLogin>
                    <d2p1:ComputerAddress i:nil="true"/>
                    <d2p1:IsFixedLogin>true</d2p1:IsFixedLogin>
                    <d2p1:IsLoggedInOtherSystem>false</d2p1:IsLoggedInOtherSystem>
                    <d2p1:Organization>myBusiness</d2p1:Organization>
                    <d2p1:Password i:nil="true"/>
                    <d2p1:Port>0</d2p1:Port>
                    <d2p1:ReadOnly>false</d2p1:ReadOnly>
                    <d2p1:Token i:nil="true"/>
                    <d2p1:User>Mustermann</d2p1:User>
                    <d2p1:UserGuid>3e90584f-ec45-4a94-b6dc-1216e3b3143e</d2p1:UserGuid>
                </d2p1:UserLogin>
            </d2p1:AIDataSource>
            <d2p1:DSFields>
                <d2p1:DataSourceField>
                    <d2p1:DisplayName>ADRESSNUMMER</d2p1:DisplayName>
                    <d2p1:InternalType>Normal</d2p1:InternalType>
                    <d2p1:IsReadonly>false</d2p1:IsReadonly>
                    <d2p1:Length>-1</d2p1:Length>
                    <d2p1:Name>ADRESSNUMMER</d2p1:Name>
                    <d2p1:Type>Text</d2p1:Type>
                </d2p1:DataSourceField>
                <d2p1:DataSourceField>
                    <d2p1:DisplayName>NAME_1</d2p1:DisplayName>
                    <d2p1:InternalType>Normal</d2p1:InternalType>
                    <d2p1:IsReadonly>false</d2p1:IsReadonly>
                    <d2p1:Length>-1</d2p1:Length>
                    <d2p1:Name>NAME_1</d2p1:Name>
                    <d2p1:Type>Text</d2p1:Type>
                </d2p1:DataSourceField>
                <d2p1:DataSourceField>
                    <d2p1:DisplayName>NAME_2</d2p1:DisplayName>
                    <d2p1:InternalType>Normal</d2p1:InternalType>
                    <d2p1:IsReadonly>false</d2p1:IsReadonly>
                    <d2p1:Length>-1</d2p1:Length>
                    <d2p1:Name>NAME_2</d2p1:Name>
                    <d2p1:Type>Text</d2p1:Type>
                </d2p1:DataSourceField>
                <d2p1:DataSourceField>
                    <d2p1:DisplayName>NAME_3</d2p1:DisplayName>
                    <d2p1:InternalType>Normal</d2p1:InternalType>
                    <d2p1:IsReadonly>false</d2p1:IsReadonly>
                    <d2p1:Length>-1</d2p1:Length>
                    <d2p1:Name>NAME_3</d2p1:Name>
                    <d2p1:Type>Text</d2p1:Type>
                </d2p1:DataSourceField>
                <d2p1:DataSourceField>
                    <d2p1:DisplayName>NAME_4</d2p1:DisplayName>
                    <d2p1:InternalType>Normal</d2p1:InternalType>
                    <d2p1:IsReadonly>false</d2p1:IsReadonly>
                    <d2p1:Length>-1</d2p1:Length>
                    <d2p1:Name>NAME_4</d2p1:Name>
                    <d2p1:Type>Text</d2p1:Type>
                </d2p1:DataSourceField>
                <d2p1:DataSourceField>
                    <d2p1:DisplayName>MATCHCODE</d2p1:DisplayName>
                    <d2p1:InternalType>Normal</d2p1:InternalType>
                    <d2p1:IsReadonly>false</d2p1:IsReadonly>
                    <d2p1:Length>-1</d2p1:Length>
                    <d2p1:Name>MATCHCODE</d2p1:Name>
                    <d2p1:Type>Text</d2p1:Type>
                </d2p1:DataSourceField>
            </d2p1:DSFields>
            <d2p1:FilterOption>Filter</d2p1:FilterOption>
            <d2p1:UsedFilter xmlns:d4p1="http://dev.mysite.com/settings/filter">
                <d4p1:Condition i:type="d4p1:ExtendedCondition">
                    <d4p1:ExtendedQuery xmlns:d6p1="http://dev.mysite.com/settings/web/querybuilder">
                        <d6p1:Root>
                            <d6p1:Conditions>
                                <d6p1:BaseCondition i:type="d6p1:Condition">
                                    <d6p1:DBName>DEL</d6p1:DBName>
                                    <d6p1:Provider i:type="d6p1:EmptyConditionProvider">
                                        <d6p1:Operation>NotEmpty</d6p1:Operation>
                                    </d6p1:Provider>
                                </d6p1:BaseCondition>
                            </d6p1:Conditions>
                            <d6p1:Operation>Or</d6p1:Operation>
                        </d6p1:Root>
                    </d4p1:ExtendedQuery>
                </d4p1:Condition>
                <d4p1:Logic>And</d4p1:Logic>
            </d2p1:UsedFilter>
        </d2p1:FCSource>
        <d2p1:IteratedRecordsAreIn>FileCabinet</d2p1:IteratedRecordsAreIn>
        <d2p1:RuleGuid>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</d2p1:RuleGuid>
        <d2p1:Version>5.1.0.1</d2p1:Version>
    </Autoindex>
    <Guid>978094cb-6cb5-4782-afdd-bf4cd11cf4ba</Guid>
    <Rule xmlns:d2p1="http://dev.mysite.com/settings/notification" i:nil="true"/>
    <ScheduleSettings xmlns:d2p1="http://dev.mysite.com/settings/common/dwschedule" i:nil="true"/>
</AutoindexBundle>```


Unfortunately, I can't change anything about the XML files; I regularly receive them from another application as setup data for documentation. Unfortunately I can't get any further here and need your help to find an approach.
